# How to Prevent Child controls moving outside of Parent control In Mouse Move Event using C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working in C#.net based windows application...In the application i am creating controls dynamically and added mouse events to that one..But while moving child control it's moving out of parent control...I tried below Code..but it's not working...So how can we do it?

```
private Point start = Point.Empty;
private bool _mapPackageIsMoving;    
Control SelectedControl = null;

 private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Name = "id1";
    lbl.Text = "move";


    lbl.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(label1_MouseDown);
    lbl.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(label1_MouseMove);
    lbl.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(label1_MouseUp);


    this.panel2.Controls.Add(lbl);

    SelectedControl = lbl;
}

void label1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _mapPackageIsMoving = false;
}

void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Label lControl = sender as Label;
    if (lControl != null)
    {
        if (_mapPackageIsMoving)
        {
        int nx = Math.Min(Math.Max(lControl.Left + (e.X - start.X), 0), lControl.Parent.Width - SelectedControl.Width);
        int ny = Math.Min(Math.Max(lControl.Top + (e.Y - start.Y), 0), lControl.Parent.Height - SelectedControl.Height);

            lControl.Location = new Point(nx, ny);
        }
    }
}

void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    start = e.Location;
    _mapPackageIsMoving = true;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that creates these controls.

Comment: @Steve Hello Sir...Above is my code..

Comment: No repro.  Only mistake I see is that you forgot lbl.AutoSize = true;

Comment: Just for testing. Set the label BorderStyle property to FixedSingle and you could see you label move correctly with the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clip the cursor, i.e. prevent it moving outside the panel that parents the label.  The changes below should help.

```
void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    start = e.Location;
    _mapPackageIsMoving = true;
    Cursor.Clip = panel2.RectangleToScreen(panel2.ClientRectangle);
}

void label1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _mapPackageIsMoving = false;
    Cursor.Clip = null;
}
```

[Drag and Drop on a Windows Form](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25692/Drag-and-Drop-on-a-Windows-Form) on CodeProject is a handy reference (the code is in VB.NET).